# Redirection from www to https

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, haproxy

I have a subdomain called for example : hello.example.com.
I can access this url using hello.example.com or https://hello.example.com.

The problem is that some of our customers use www.hello.example.com which doesnt show the website.I tried multiple redirection methods. But none is working perfectly.

Our environment : The website is hosted in 4 aws instances with 2 haproxy load balancers(total 6 instances). The domain is routed in aws Route 53.

I Tried 3 methods:
1. Adding a redirect rule in haproxy.cfg file "redirect prefix hello.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.hello.example.com }"

2. Adding rewrite rule in .htaccess file in my document root
3. By adding www.hello.example.com in route53 ad route it to a s3 bucket with same name and using static website hosting to redirect it to hello.example.com

I am getting ssl certificate error while using the 1st method. I think this has something to do with the url being a subdomain.I have wildcard certificate for *.example.com . So this doesnt work for www.hello.example.com

The second method doesnt do anything.

And with third method i sometimes get the website using www, but not always. If i clear my cache and then search for it i will git using www, but only for 1 time.

Comment: What methods have you tried? Can you give some examples?

Comment: @GašperČefarin I Tried 3 methods:

1. Adding a redirect rule in haproxy.cfg file
"redirect prefix https://hello.example.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.hello.example.com }"

2. Adding rewrite rule in .htaccess file in my document root

3. By adding www.hello.example.com in route53 ad route it to a s3 bucket with same name and using static website hosting to redirect it to https://hello.example.com

Comment: I am getting ssl certificate error while using the 1st method. I think this has something to do with the url being a subdomain.I have wildcard certificate for *.example.com . So this doesnt work for www.hello.example.com.

Comment: Couly you please [edit] your question and add the details from your comment to the question itslef?